# Can't read custom environment variables in node using config.get()

Tags: node.js, express, config

I use [config library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) to manage my configuration files in node application.

I have export my custom env variable in terminal by 
  `export app_password=12345`

and map it into the `custom-environment-variable.json` file by

```
{
  "mail": {
  "password": "app_password"
   }
}
```

when I use `config.get('mail.password')` in my index.js file (root module) .

I got `error: Configuration property "mail.password" is not defined`, detail in below:

```
/Users/tzhong/Documents/vidly- 
backend/node_modules/config/lib/config.js:203
throw new Error('Configuration property "' + property + '" is not 
defined');
^

Error: Configuration property "mail.password" is not defined
    at Config.get (/Users/tzhong/Documents/vidly- 
 backend/node_modules/config/lib/config.js:203:11)
```

I have use `console.log(process.env.app_password)` to check if my custom env variable is there, and the app_password show in the terminal.

```
 Vidly evn is : Vidly backend -- development
 Vidly mail server is : dev-mail-server
 Mail-password is : 12345
 NODE_ENV is : undefined
 app: development
 Mongan enabled...
 Listenning 3000 port ...
```

I want to use `console.log(config.get('mail.password'));` to show my custom variable in terminal instead of `console.log(process.env.app_password)`
Any suggestions?

Finally solve the problem :
It's tiny mistake, in config library, the file's name for creating custom environment variable is strict, the file's name should be `'custom-environment-variables.json'`, I have a wrong spell on `'environment'` , after all , thanks for people offer other available package

Answer (score 3):

Rename the filename to 'custom-environment-variables.json' with a plural "variables".

Answer (score 1):

Right way to do this in `nodejs` is to make use of `.env` file. Create a `.env` file at the root. Keep your env variables and their value there in the `key=value` format for e.g `password=app_password`

In your main entry point file, Require the `dotenv` package and load the env variables with `dotenv.configure()` at the top just after requiring all the modules. See [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) for more details.

Comment: Hey Rajesh, thanks for the suggestion, but do you know what wrong in my code when I using config library?

Comment: I have solve the problem, the path for config.get('mail.password') is okey, just the custom environment variables file name should be correct

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with VS Code Terminal. It not picking the file or object.
Try external node terminal. It will work.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using config use **.env**. Just simply add by typing **npm install --save dotenv**

```
password=some value
```

You can access this by

```js
require("dotenv").config();

console.log(`Password is ${process.env.password}.`);
//Output
Password is *some value*
```

Comment: hi namus, I think I can use console.log(process.env.password) without dotenv package, I want to do the same thing with config package.Thank for your comment